# What is the pseudoinverse of a singular square matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

All matrices have a pseudoinverse. However, I cannot prove this for a singular square matrix.

The pseudoinverse of a matrix is given as

$$A^{+} = (A^{T}A)^{-1}A^{T}$$

$$(A^{T}A)^{-1} = \frac{C^{T}}{det(A^{T}A)} = \frac{C^{T}}{det(A^{T})det(A)}$$

So wouldn't

$$(A^{T}A)^{-1}$$
be singular, which means the a pseudoinverse does not exist for a singular square matrix. Am I wrong? If so how?

Comment: Your pseudoinverse formula is for tall matrices with full column rank. Is that your case?

Comment: If $A$ is singular then the above formula cannot work. There are various approaches to defining the pseudo inverse. While slightly cumbersome, I like defining $A^\dagger x$ as the minimum norm solution to $\min_x {1 \over 2} \|Ax-b\|$.

Comment: Take a look at [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2373397/339790). Or [this example](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2141476/339790).

Comment: @copper.hat So would it be correct to say that a pseudo-inverse does not exist for a singular square matrix. If we take this definition.

Comment: @cojoye: Correct. Just because $A^TA$ is not invertible.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo: Read the last sentence of the OP's comment.

Comment: Another definition I like is $A^\dagger = \lim_{t \downarrow 0} (A^*A+tI)^{-1} A^*$, or the SVD definition.